# Getting a value from a database and echoing from another file

Tags: php

I am trying to Select a row from a database table and display the variables in another PHP file. Right now I have to trying just one variable, but will change to outputting a table later on. The error is an Undefined Variable:output.

I have tried using session but it prints out the array and doesn't go all the way through. I really just want the variable so that I can put them into a table easier.

My store file, which shows a search bar and where I am trying to display the results, under the search bar.

```
<?php
  require "header.php";
?>

<main>

<form action="includes/itemsearch.php" method="get">
  Please enter the Item you are looking for:<br>
  <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Search for an item...">
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" name="search-submit">Search</button>
</form>
<?php echo $output ?>
</main>



<?php
  require "footer.php";
?>
```

My item search file:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['search-submit'])) {
  require 'connect.php';


  $item = $_GET['item'];
  $output = "";

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Product";

  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $pName =$row['Product_Name'];
    $manufacture=$row['Manufacture'];
    $quantity=$row['Quantity'];
    $price=$row['Price'];
    $description=$row['Description'];
    echo"<p>$pName</p><br />";
  }
  header("Location: ../store.php?");

}
```

I currently get an undefined variable error.

Comment: you forgot to put `;` at end of `echo $output` ,also what does `$output` have in it ?

Comment: why don't you try to include `itemsearch.php` in your `store.php`

Answer (score 0):

$output is undefined because you initialize it on click of submit button so `<?php echo $output ?>` is executing first then it gets initialized.

try

```
<?php 
     if (isset($_GET['search-submit'])){
          echo $output;
     }
?>
```

to get output just require search file in store.php

```
// store.php

<?php
  require "header.php";
  require "search.php";
?>

<main>

<form action="" method="get">
  Please enter the Item you are looking for:<br>
  <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Search for an item...">
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" name="search-submit">Search</button>
</form>
<?php echo $output ?>
</main>



<?php
  require "footer.php";
?>
```

this is the final code

```
// search.php
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['search-submit'])) {
      require 'connect.php';


      $item = $_GET['item'];
      $output = "";

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM Product";

      $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $pName =$row['Product_Name'];
        $manufacture=$row['Manufacture'];
        $quantity=$row['Quantity'];
        $price=$row['Price'];
        $description=$row['Description'];
        $output .= "<p>$pName</p><br />";
      }

    }

?>

// store.php
<?php
  require "header.php";
  require "search.php";
?>

<main>

<form action="" method="get">
  Please enter the Item you are looking for:<br>
  <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Search for an item...">
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" name="search-submit">Search</button>
</form>
<?php echo isset($_GET['search-submit']) ? $output : '' ?>
</main>



<?php
  require "footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: Okay this fixes the error, but still no output on the store page.

Comment: to each $output on store.php require search file in store.php and remove header code. (I've updated my answer)

Comment: I added it at the top and am still getting the same result.

Comment: just I see you did initialize $output = ''; but when you are changing the value of $output?

Comment: I just added $output=$pname above the echo search.php, also echo"$output" now, not $pname.

Answer (score 0):

use post method instead of get

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search-submit'])) {

}
?>
```

Comment: No error anymore, still nothing echoing on the store page.